# HtmlWebpackPlugin hook not called in CRA

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, react-scripts, html-webpack-plugin, react-app-rewired

I'm using `react-scripts` 4.0.3 and `react-app-rewired` 2.1.6 to make some adjustments to the webpack config.

I want to alter some attributes of the script tags that are generated and injected into `index.html`. I'm using `alterAssetTags` hook of the `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

```
class MyPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('MyPlugin', compilation => {
      console.log('compilation'); // <- this is executed
      HtmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks(compilation).alterAssetTags.tap('MyPlugin', data => {
         console.log('adjust tags'); // <- not executed
      });
    });
  }
}
```

This is my `config-overrides.js`:

```
const { override, addWebpackPlugin, babelInclude } = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = function (config, env) {
  return Object.assign(
    config,
    override(
      addWebpackPlugin(new MyPlugin()),
      babelInclude([
        path.resolve('src'), // don't forget this
      ])
    )(config, env)
  );
};
```

#### Problem

The problem is, that `alterAssetTags` is not called during the build process (but the `compilation` hook is).

However, if I replace the existing `HtmlWebpackPlugin` of create-react-app, everything works as expected.

```
const htmlWebpackPluginIndex = config.plugins.findIndex(plugin => plugin.constructor.name === 'HtmlWebpackPlugin');
const newHtmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   ...config.plugins[htmlWebpackPluginIndex].options,
 });
// Replace the original HtmlWebpackPlugin with the new instance
config.plugins.splice(htmlWebpackPluginIndex, 1, newHtmlWebpackPlugin);
config.plugins.push(new MyPlugin());
```

This is not a solution though, because the generated `index.html` differs.

#### Question

What could be the issue, that `alterAssetTags` is not called?

Comment: You can try to use new modern html-bundler-webpack-plugin. This plugin allow to define source script/style files directly in HTML template, so you can self specify needed tag attributes.